# Git Hooks: only post-update is working

Tags: git, cocoapods, githooks

I'm having an issue with **git hooks**.

Here is what I'm trying to do (I'll tell you then, what I'm really doing and what's the problem).

I'm experimenting something on my iMac.
I have a git user with **2 big parts** with git repositories `git init --bare...`

One is for different **pod projects**:

- pod1.git
- pod2.git
- ...

The other is **2 specs** repos to insert "source ..." into podfiles then:

- UIKitSpecs.git
- FoundationSpecs.git

The idea is to have some internal (for a client) pods xcode projects (on a macMini or something).
What I want to do is to push the podspec and create the good directory with the good version (depending on the last tag) on the good spec git repo!
I can handle the script to push automatically etc..

The point is that on my "podx.git" repos, hooks (in the /hooks folder) don't work at all except post-update.
I tried to commit, commit -m "message", push etc...
Just the post-update is called after a push!

I removed the .sample prefix, and run the chmod +x command on them even if they already was executables.

Any solution?

Comment: Can you please take a look at the suggestions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263689/git-pre-commit-hook-not-working-on-windows/34265906#34265906 ? The usual suspects are a bad shebang line OR trying to run python hooks on Windows.  It would also help if you could post a snippet of the hook that is NOT running.

Comment: @AshutoshJindal : Here are the content of my commit-msg and pre-commit hooks : "#!/bin/sh -x
echo "Commit-MSG test!?"
And the same for pre-commit ! Nothing BIG! Just edited as said in the sample files !

Comment: And here is my commit Message: "jgdx@MAC-P892 ~/D/projet> touch tata
jgdx@MAC-P892 ~/D/projet> git add .
jgdx@MAC-P892 ~/D/projet> git commit -m "Working?"
[master 0caf5c6] Working?
 Committer: MY NAME <name@MAC-P892.local>
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 tata"

Comment: OK I tried to put some bash code client-side! For the pre-commit etc... And I guess, maybe some are only working server-side, and other only client-side? Bc yeah commits are only indexing client-side.... This should help some people: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks . TELL ME IF I'M WRONG With this conclusion ?